# configparser: Not reading the file from the given path

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, configparser

Below is my python project structure in eclipse. I am using configparser to read a section in settings.config file. The configparser is not parsing the file. It shows No Section specified but I have correctly mentioned the section. I am creating a dockerfile and when I run docker-compose file, the path is shown as

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MyProject-0.0.1-py3.6.egg/Publisher/settings.config

```
MyProject
 -Client
    -__init__.py
    -Main.py
 -Publisher
    -domain1
    -domain2
        -__init__.py
        -config.py
        -callconfig.py
    -__init__.py
    -settings.config

#config.py
import os.path as path
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # ver. < 3.0
        class Config(object):

        def get(self, mykey):
            config = ConfigParser()   
            configpath = path.join(path.split(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))[0], "settings.config") 
            print (configpath)
            config.read(configpath)
            myvalue = config.get('mysection', mykey)
```

Comment: Fix you identation and are you executing Config().get() ?

Comment: Indentation is fixed. Yes executing `config.get('mysection', mykey)`

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the parent folder path or just go one hierarchy up

```
  configpath = 'Publisher/settings.config'
    config.read(configpath)
```